# PHP variable value not updating

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, scope

this is my first question here, but I use this a lot, so sorry for anything.

```
   foreach($quizzData->questions->children() as $quest)
        {
            $questDesc = $quest->direction;
            $offset = 1;

            if(strpos($questDesc, "student") !== false)
            {
                foreach($quest->answers->children() as $questChild)
                {
                    $name = trim($questChild);
                    $result = $db->executeSQL("CALL SPU_SE_STUDENT_ID('$name')")->fetch_assoc();
                    $studentID = $result['ID_STUDENT'];
                    $db->freeResult();
                    $pos = $questChild['userDefinedPosition'] + $offset;

                    if( $quizSummary['studentID'] == $studentID)
                    {
                        $offset = 0;
                        $sql = "CALL SPU_IN_STUDENT_EVAL_SUMMARY ($period, {$quizSummary['studentID']}, $studentID,0)"; 
                        $db->executeSQL($sql);
                        $db->freeResult();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $sql = "CALL SPU_IN_STUDENT_EVAL_SUMMARY ($period, {$quizSummary['studentID']}, $studentID,$pos)"; 
                        $db->executeSQL($sql);
                        $db->freeResult(); 
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

The Code runs without errors, but the variable $offset doesn't change inside the if, and the if code IS being executed because I validated it on the database.
The $db variable is an instance of another class, and that class doesn't have any variables named $offset.
I Have no idea why it's not working, can anyone help me ?

***EXAMPLE:***
 I have 4 students that are ranked, but one of them is the student himself, let´s say student A. 
The array index where they are starts at 0, but I can't have the rank 0, so I add the offset 1. 
Then I do the inner foreach for the for students and it should go like:

```
Student C 0(index) + 1(offset) = 1   
Student B 1(index) + 1(offset) = 2   
Student A = 0  
Student D 3(index) + 0(offset)
```

After all 4 students are evaluated I go back to the outer foreach and reset $offset to 1. However what happens is that after Student A the $offset is not set to 0 as per the line `$offset = 0;`. And I know that this block of code is being executed.

Thanks a lot in advance.

***Solved***
The problem was that I was told the array with the ranking would be ordered, but it's not, not a php problem, just a communication problem between the user and me.
Thanks for the help.
And to whoever downvoted my question I assume you know all about everything right genious.

Comment: You realize that `$offset` gets set back to `1` in the next iteration of your outer `foreach` loop right? So even if it's changing, it gets changed right back.

Comment: Hi jszobody. Yes, this is correct, it needs to be set back on the outer loop, I use the offset because of the index[0], it's a ranking that when the Student is himself it 0's the rank and sets the offset to 0 because the next index will be the right value.

Comment: I'm not seeing what the problem is then. You have a variable, it is being changed, but then being changed back. What do you expect to happen here that isn't happening?

Comment: Let me do an example:
I have 4 students that are ranked, but one of them is the student himself, let´s say student A.
The array index starts at 0, so I do the inner foreach to loop the students, but I can't have the rank 0, so I add the offset 1.
Then it goes like:
Student C 0(index) + 1(offset) = 1
Student B 1(index) + 1(offset) = 2
Student A = 0
Student D 3(index) + 0(offset)

After all 4 students are evaluated I go back to the outer foreach and reset $offset to 1

Answer (score 0):

Solved The problem was that I was told the array with the ranking would be ordered, but it's not, not a php problem, just a communication problem between the user and me. Thanks for the help. And to whoever downvoted my question I assume you know all about everything right genious.